# JDK or OpenJDK to self-teach Android App Development

Tags: android, java

I am auditing Coursera's **Learn Java for Android** (so it's not like I can ask the instructors)

The instructor says

> It requires the Java JDK to first be installed. In the future, Android
>   released N to be specific. The software developers of Android will be
>   moving away from the official Java JDK, instead moving to the open
>   source Java Development Kit, called Open JDK.

Android N just released, isn't it?

As someone who is self-teaching themselves Android app development, it is adviseable to follow the video and still use Java JDK? Or it it better to use Open JDK

Comment: *"Android N just released, isn't it?"* No, [Android "Nougat"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Nougat) was released on August 22, 2016, more than a year ago.

Comment: Difficult to answer unless you tell us what you are considering as the alternative to that video.  But bear in mind that the difficult parts of learning Android App development are 1) learning to program, 2) learning Java, 3) learning the Java + Android APIs, and 4) getting your head around what is available in terms of 3rd-party libraries, etc.  The tool chain is a tiny part of what you will be learning.

Comment: Also, if you are really talking about Oracle JDK versus OpenJDK, the differences (for Android programmers) are pretty much non-existent.

Comment: @StephenC Luckily I know how to program and I'm familiar with Java. I'm not sure if there is alternative to video (although I'm sure there are lot of YouTUBE videos out there). I guess my question is should I follow the video and use JDK till I am more familiar with Andriod programming, or should I use Open JDK to start with. I wasn't aware of Oracle JDK.

Comment: 1) Oracle JDK is Java JDK.  In fact Oracle JDK / Java JDK are *closely related* to OpenJDK.  They built from a common source codebase. 2) Given that the differences are pretty much non-existent (see previous comment), it makes no difference which you use for Android.

Comment: What happened with Android N is that the Android Operating System itself moved from (Oracle) JDK to Open JDK. This has no impact on which jdk you use to develop apps in. Either one will work just fine

Comment: Ok then I'll just follow Coursera tutorial very closely for now